# Pre-filling a hosted MailChimp signup form with an email address shows validation errors

Tags: validation, mailchimp

We're trying to pre-fill the email address field of a hosted MailChimp form. Here's the blog post that talks about exactly this matter: https://blog.mailchimp.com/how-to-pre-fill-items-on-your-mailchimp-hosted-form/.

So here's our Newsletter signup form **without any validation errors**:
https://camping.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=761a52bbd46ab21474b3af314&id=5cc638b5e6.

The problem arises when I add an email address to the URL as the value for the first form field, `MERGE0`, like this (url-encoding the email address, so `@` becomes `%40`):
https://camping.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=761a52bbd46ab21474b3af314&id=5cc638b5e6&MERGE0=test%40camping.info.

Now, the form correctly copies the email address into the `input` field with name `MERGE0` but it **also** displays **three** validation error messages:

[image]

Note: the email address field is **mandatory**.
When I try to pre-fill the user's first or last name fields adding `MERGE1=John` or `MERGE2=Doe` to the form's url, **all is well** - no error happens. It seems to be a problem with mandatory fields.

I'm arguing that this is a problem on **MailChimp's** side but they refuse to help saying that this is custom code and none of their business.

Can anybody help fix these errors?

Comment: From the blog post it looks like you "design" the form yourself - is that true?  I have never used mailChimp before but it sounds like they are refusing to help you because they are claiming that the HTML form is custom (i.e. you designed it) and therefore its breaking because of that design.  I see that you are claiming its the server side processing (https://camping.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post)

Comment: So I've tried doing this a number of ways including using SoapUI to generate the POST request and using the browser - my only theory is that its possible that you must include ALL required fields at once (this isn't the right behavior but it's possible that's the bug) - however I cannot get the radio buttons to take the "checked" value: https://camping.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=761a52bbd46ab21474b3af314&id=5cc638b5e6&MERGE0=matthewrishii@gmail.com&MERGE1=Matthew&MERGE2=Ishii&MERGE[3][0]=true&MERGE4[0]=true&MERGE5[0]=true

Comment: Oliver - have you tried setting all the mandatory fields in the URL?  It may be a bug with their server side script that if one required field is included, they are all required to be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was caused by a mistake in the URL.

Instead of

```
camping.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/POST?u=761a52bbd46ab...
```

it had to be

```
camping.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=761a52bbd46ab...
```

And the errors were gone!

This really made sense in the end, because *posting* the form should actually trigger the *validation*.